# arranging icons and layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these icons that float to the right but they don't align properly and i want to fix them so if one icon in the middle is missing - the icon on the left will move properly into the middle part. I wanted them to be flexible depending on adding and deleting and moving icons.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67pun/

```
<span  class="toggleIcon accordion_collapse_icon float_right icon-minus"> + </span>

<span class="float_right week_date_range">Dec 2 - 6</span>

<a id="editElement" class="btn_inline_block float_left btn_edit_element"> @
                    </a>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion_collapse_icon {
position: relative;
top: 15px;
right: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}

week_date_range {
position: relative;
top: 13px;
right: 40px;
color: #a5a5a5;
}
.btn_inline_block {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.float_right, .float-right {
float: right;
}
[class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline;
width: auto;
height: auto;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: baseline;
background-image: none;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans Sorry missed clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of your desired final output.  Here's a stab at it: http://jsfiddle.net/HW8E6/

I added a wrapping container and floated it right:

```
.container {
    float: right;
}
```

I will say that typically when floating right, I like to float a surrounding container and then include my items.  The reason for this, is that to float everything right one by one you have to add them in reverse order.  If you float a container, then you can keep them in logical order.

Comment: Thanks but i needed all the icons to be on the same line.